# Enable hot deploy for web pages in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, hotdeploy

i am new to jboss, and i want to enable the hot deploy feature as in tomcat.
right now when making any change to the xhtml page, i rebuild the application then redeploy the whole war, which is too much.

but in tomcat the war file was extracted, and then i replace the change xhtml file only and see the change immediately.

i was wondering how to accomplish same behavior for jboss-as-7.1.1.Final, and not in eclipse.

please advise how to do that, thanks.

Comment: If your war file name is myapp.war. For deployment you may be creating a file myapp.war.dodeploy which will get changed to myapp.war.deployed after you deployed. You can just change this filename back to myapp.war.dodeploy to redeploy with your change.

Comment: Does an exploded war file with ant synch task recognizes the changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same thing in JBoss as well. The file should be in /tmp/vfs/temp*/content* in the jboss server (standalone) directory. You can simply find the xhtml in that directory, and replace with new one. It should work! ..

It looks there is another way using jsp-configuration developement=true, check [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=462)

Answer (score 2):

Add to your project this in the web.xml-> jboss detected and enable hot deploy.

```
 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>development</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
```

or u can use the new jboss as 6 its supposedly fixed. or u can follow this link instructions:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-659

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way of acomplishing it is using eclipse and selecting an option: deploy on server. To do that you need JBoss plugin in eclipse. It will do it automaticaly for you. So far no problems with it. The only issue is that if you change beans, you need to do the 'full publish'.

Comment: Where is that setting: "deploy on server"? I have JBoss plugin installed but I can't find this setting?