# Avoid repeating tasks (log in, go to page) when developing web applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, jboss, jboss7.x

I am developing an application that requires a login before I can access a certain page.

Is there an easy way to bypass certain actions so that I don't have to log in and go to the actual page that I am developing/testing after the deployment of my application?

I can think of the following:

1. use some record/replay plugin in my browser, replay after each deployment
2. edit the application so that it works without login at dev-time

The first one is good, because I don't have to touch the code. Yet it is bad, because it is slow. Second one vice versa.

Isn't there some option for the application server (JBoss AS 7 here) to save the state of the last deployment and just bring me back there? How is this usually done?

Another thing I know is "hot deployment", which works fine for the `.xhtml` files, but I've never been able to run it with java files. Is this an option?

Answer (score 3):

About hot deployment see http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Answer (score 0):

In theory, whether its xhtml, jsp or any other, the hot deployment should work. Incase of Java file, you need to copy the generated .class file to the proper location.

please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723069/enable-hot-deploy-for-web-pages-in-jboss-as-7-1-1-final/) how to do it in jboss7.

Once you replace the .class/html/jsp etc, if you reload it should work.